# Converting a dataclass with a field of the dictionary type, where the other dataclass is the keof dicty

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

How to convert dataclass to python dictionary? In this case, one of the fields of the data class contains a dictionary, the key of which is another data class. It seems to be necessary, in some way, to convert the nested dataclass into a tuple

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Two:
    a:str = 'World'
@dataclass
class First:
    a: str = 'Hello'
    b: set[Two] = field(default_factory=lambda: set())
    c: defaultdict = field(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(set))
    d: defaultdict[Two, set] = field(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(set))
    f: str = None

obj = First()
obj.b.add(Two())
obj.d[Two('!')].add(1)
obj
```

I have the following code, but unfortunately it throws an error:

```py
import dataclass_factory



factory = dataclass_factory.Factory()
factory.dump(obj)
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    address: str
    phone: str

person = Person("John", 30, "532 Main Street", "555-434-502")
person_dict = asdict(person)

print(person_dict)
# Output: {'name': 'John', 'age': 30, 'address': '123 Main Street'}
```

To convert a Python `dataclass` into a dictionary, you can use the `asdict` function provided by the `dataclasses` module.

Hopefully this will lead you in the right direction, although I'm unsure about nested `dataclasses`.

Comment: Nested ```dataclasses``` unfortunately cannot be converted this way

Comment: @akseart Is there any way you can maybe convert the child first and then the parent?